# MasterPage Load Theme

Tags: c#, themes, master-pages, preinit

on asp.net C#,
i want to change the theme when page is load, this action requiers PreInit Event, Which Masterpage dont have. what is the solution for that issue?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an [Http Module (Rick van den Bosch blogs)](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2007/10/20/howto-set-the-theme-for-a-masterpage-from-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from an Module, you could consider having all your pages inherit from a base page that defines PreInit and sets the theme accordingly.

Edit for comment.

There isn't all that much to it, just make sure the pages you create inherit from a class similar to the `BasePage` class below instead of the default `Page` class and you should be set.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
  public BasePage()
  {
    this.PreInit += new EventHandler(BasePage_PreInit);
  }

  protected void BasePage_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Page.Theme = theme; //Garner from appropriate resource
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.